# Objects with transparent texture disappear when zooming out

Tags: particles, eevee-render-engine, transparency

Context:
I wanted to make a tree, so I created some digital branches that I apply as a particle system onto the tree. These branches are made out of textures that have transparency.

The Problem:
Then I noticed that in EEVEE, the branch-objects disappear when zooming too far out. And not just the objects, but also the particles on the tree.

Does anyone know how to turn that off, or at least control it? I want to render that tree from a distance and the branches need to be seen.

[I posted a short video of my problem on Twitter](https://twitter.com/MarcoLanger5/status/1402691882329817090)

Comment: What blend mode are you using for the transparent material? Does switching it help?

Comment: I'm using the "Alpha Clip" Blend Mode.

Comment: Does switching to alpha-blend make it any better? If not, what's your camera end-clip distance settings? I can confirm that when zooming out from an object, there is a "spot" right before the object clips out of view when the object is still visible but the particles disappear. Have you changed anything with your camera settings?

Comment: Yeah, indeed. Changing the Blend Mode to Alpha Hashed or Alpha Blend does fix it. I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you.

Comment: You might also consider changing the image texture to "closest" instead of "linear" and see if that helps, instead of changing blend mode.  I suspect texture filtering is leading to an alpha lookup less than clip-- the two are interacting.

Comment: Yes. Changing the texture interpolation to "closest" solves the problem too.